# Get files and folders from drag and drop in Electron crashes/error

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to retrieve folders or files when they are dropped onto the Electron application.

My code is as follows:

index.html

```
<div id="mainGrid" class="ag-theme-alpine-dark" style="width:100%;height90vh;">
```

main.js

```
ipcMain.handle('getFiles', (event, filePaths) => {

    let files = [];
   
    try {

        console.log(filePaths)
        return files;

    } catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
   }

});
```

renderer.js

```
let dropArea = document.getElementById('mainGrid');

;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false);
});
dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

function preventDefaults (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
};

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    let paths = e.dataTransfer.files;
    // send files to be processed
    let files = window.ipcRender.invoke('getFiles', paths);

};
```

preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "ipcRender", {
        send: (channel, args) => {
            ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
    
        },
        sendSync: (channel, args)  => {
            return ipcRenderer.sendSync(channel, args);  
        },
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
        },
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
        }
    }
);
```

When I start the app and drag a few folders on to it, I get:

```
DevTools was disconnect from the page.
Once page is reloaded. DevTools will automatically reconnect.
```

So I am assuming it is crashing, however for the life of me (forgive me I am new to electron) I can't see how this would crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your **renderer.js** is plagued with semicolon problems… so much so it’s amazing it ever got off the ground!

Here's a corrected version:

```
let dropArea = document.getElementById('mainGrid');

['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
    dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false);
});

dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

function preventDefaults (e){ e.preventDefault();  e.stopPropagation();}

function handleDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    let paths = e.dataTransfer.files;
    // send files to be processed
    let files = window.ipcRender.invoke('getFiles', paths);

}
```

In future you can use an online JavaScript compiler like Rhino, to check your syntax:

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-rhino-online/

Comment: Thanks, however it did nothing to fix the actual issue :(

Comment: One step at a time mate… that's how we get closer and closer to a solution! :)

Comment: You’re not getting the actual error displayed... use this:  window.onerror=function(e){alert(e.stack);};

Comment: I just added error handling, unfortunately it does the same thing, nothing shows up in console

Comment: Why the console? Are you running this in the console? An alert box should pop up by the window error handler!

Comment: Step3: You gotta use: try{} catch(e){alert(e);} in all vulnerable places…

Comment: I'm sorry, I used console.log instead of alert, forgot to mention. I just changed it to alert, and still nothing

Comment: Just added try catch in the handleDrop function, and still same results, the try catch is already on the .handle('getFiles')

Comment: I added async and await to the handleDrop, and now I get an alert that says: Error: An object could not be cloned